# how to delete duplicates in hashsets in java and store in third hashset

Tags: java

I want to delete duplicates totally from hashsets.

For example:

- hashset `names1` contains `a, b, c, d`
- hashset `names2` contains `x, y, z, a`

I want that hashset `names3` should have `b, c, d, x, y, z`

Deleting the common element between the 2 hashsets and storing it in third hashset.how to do this?

Comment: There are no common elements in either set to begin with so it's hard to understand what you want. Edit your question...

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Show us some code

Comment: So, you want the set union minus the intersection?

Comment: @tobias_k, that's how I read it too.

Comment: @fge `a` is common to both.

Comment: You're looking for the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the unique elements, you need to find the *union* of both sets, minus their *intersection*.

You can achieve this using the `addAll`, `retainAll` and `removeAll` methods of `Set`:

```
Set union = new HashSet(setA);
union.addAll(setB);

Set intersection = new HashSet(setA);
intersection.retainAll(setB);

Set unique = new HashSet(union);
unique.removeAll(intersection);
```

Comment: This is the correct (and functioning) solution. Here's an [ideone](http://ideone.com/mbV1WD) for you, OP.

Answer (score 1):

You want the Union of the two HashSets, minus the intersection. So, basically, the unique items from both sets:

```
public void union(Set<E> s){
    set.addAll(s);
}

public void intersection(Set<E> s){ 
    set.retainAll(s);
}

public void unique(Set<E> s){
   set.addAll( set.union(s).removeAll( set.intersection(s) );
}
```

Comment: The idea is sound, but the implementation seems very odd. First, all those operations modify `set`, so I guess there would be all sorts of unwanted behaviour. Also, `union` and `intersection` don't return anything, so this won't even compile. If this is pseudo-code, please mark it as such.

Comment: I'd love to provide working code, but then we need to see the code of @user3569467. If this is someone's homework, then I'm happy to advice but not do it for them.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the intersection between 2 list and than remove than from the union list:

find all intersection

```
Set<String> uniques = new HashSet<String>(names1);
uniqueNums.retainAll(names2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this is the union minus the intersection. To implement that easily, you can use [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) or [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) libraries. Here's the code using the Commons Collections `CollectionUtils` class:

```
Collection result = CollectionUtils.union(set1, set2);
result.removeAll(CollectionUtils.intersection(set1, set2));
```

`result` will be a Collection, which can be converted to a set using `new HashSet(result)`

---

Here's the implementation using Google's Guava library `Sets` class:

```
HashSet result = new HashSet(Sets.union(set1, set2));
result.removeAll(Sets.intersection(set1, set2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to modify the Set1 and Set2.

```
1. Find Largest Set and add to new one.
2. Iterate Small Set and if it already exists remove , else add it.
public static <E> Set<E>  getIntersection(Set<E> set1, Set<E> set2) {
        boolean set1IsLarger = set1.size() > set2.size();
        Set<E> smallerSet = set1IsLarger ? set2 : set1;
        Set<E> largerSet = set1IsLarger ? set1 : set2;
        Set<E> intersection = new HashSet<E>(set1.size()+set2.size());
        intersection.addAll(largerSet);
        for (E value : smallerSet) {
            if (!largerSet.contains(value)){
                intersection.add(value);
            }else{
                intersection.remove(value);
            }
        }
        return intersection;
    }
```